# How do I sync my Outlook calendar with my iPhone 4

Tags: itunes, iphone, ms-office, ios

How do I sync my outlook calendar with iPhone 4?

I failed to sync my outlook calendar with my iPhone 4.

Since I upgraded my iTunes to 11 there is no box to check for this option like in the old iTunes versions.

Comment: Are you on OSX or Windows?

Comment: i am using Windows

Answer (score 2):

Use the iCloud Control Panel for Windows
[image]
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455